# Are rotary encoders necessary for holonomic mecanum drive?

Tags: mobile-robot, motor

I'm making a robot which is going to have a holonomic mecanum drive. The doubt that I'm having is that should I use rotary encoders for doing so.
The bot will be manually controlled so would it be possible for me to ignore the rotary encoders?

#### Clarification

The thing is that I need to decide whether or not I'll be using motors with rotary encoders in my robot.
**What I'm thinking:**
  Is it really necessary for me to use rotary encoders for implementing holonomic drive? I know that holonomic motion is attained through the appropriate vector sum of velocities generated by the motors. But since the bot is going to be manually controlled, can't I ignore the accuracy of the motion(by not using rotary encoders) as the controlling human **might** himself be managing those errors simply by seeing the bot's motion.

Comment: that would be the purpose of the encoders?

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: @MarkBooth I have clarified the question a bit. Please have a look.

Comment: It would be better to have a single question rather than an unclear question followed by a clarification. I'll re-open the question, but I think it would be more likely to attract answers if you improved it further.